# Control servo driver with Matlab via RaspberryPi

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi

I've got a adafruit 16-channel 12-bit pwm/servo driver connected to my raspberrypi and I'm wondering if there's a way to control the servos with Matlab?

Comment: MATLAB on the R-Pi or MATLAB on a PC connected to the R-Pi? Both should be possible

Comment: MATLAB on a PC connectec to RPI.